# How can run HTML(Object Tag)+Flash(AS3.0) Video Player in Wamp Server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video-streaming, video-player

I have created a flash FLVPlayBack video(swf). Embeded in html play with object tag. Video also putted in relative path. It is not playing. How can play??

Please help me, it should url with localhost or only video. & also security error occurs.

Flash AS3.0

```
var vid:Video;
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
var customClient:Object = new Object();
customClient.onMetaData = metaDataHandler;
ns.client = customClient;
ns.play(url);


vid = new Video();
vid.x = 0;
vid.y = 0;
vid.width = 400;
vid.height = 300;
vid.attachNetStream(ns);
addChild(vid);

function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void 
{
    trace(event.text);
}

function metaDataHandler(infoObject:Object):void {
    //vid.width = infoObject.width;
    //vid.height = infoObject.height;
    vid.width = 400;
vid.height = 300;
}
```

HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <title>testVideo</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    </head>
<body>

<!-- using query string -->
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0"
width="550"
height="400"
align="middle"
id="main">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="main.swf?one=1&two=2" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<embed src="main.swf?one=1&two=2"
width="550"
height="400"
autostart="false"
quality="high"
bgcolor="#ffffff"
name="main"
align="middle"
allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: You say security errors occur in addition to other errors? Can you provide a detailed output of all errors that occur?

Comment: Cross domain.. It solved by added cross domain xml